# How to add video description in TikTok Web Kit

Tags: node.js, tiktok

I was able to successfully publish a video to TikTok via the API but I have a little issue which is:

In addition to the video parameter, how can I also add a video description to the TikTok request body

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://open-api.tiktok.com/share/video/upload/?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>&open_id=<OPEN_ID>' \
--form 'video=@"/Users/bytedance/Downloads/video.mp4"'
```

I added description in the form and they discarded it and took only the video parameter.

It seems they don't accept descriptions.

They take only the video parameter?